# React Native: How to detect if an app has come to the foreground on start/after closing the app from AppSwitcher?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I want to be able to subscribe an event listener when my React Native app comes to the foreground.

React Native has the [AppState](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate) APIs for these, the official documentation on which has the following example

```
const AppStateExample = () => {
  const appState = useRef(AppState.currentState);
  const [appStateVisible, setAppStateVisible] = useState(appState.current);

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = AppState.addEventListener("change", nextAppState => {
      if (
        appState.current.match(/inactive|background/) &&
        nextAppState === "active"
      ) {
        console.log("App has come to the foreground!");
      }

      appState.current = nextAppState;
      setAppStateVisible(appState.current);
    });

    return () => {
      subscription.remove();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
      <Text>Current state is: {appStateVisible}</Text>
  );
};
```

My problem is this doesn't work when the app starts for the first time, or after I close the app on iOS from the AppSwitcher by an upwards swipe.

How can I detect the state change when the app is started for the first time after having been closed from the AppSwitcher? As far as I can tell, the state, in that case, is `background`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the if statement to something like this:

```
  if (
    appState.current.match(/inactive|background/) &&
    nextAppState === 'active'
  ) {
    console.log('App has come to the foreground!');
  } else {
    console.log('App state', nextAppState);
  }
```

If you start the app and then close it with an upward swipe, you should see the following log output:

```
 LOG  Running "appstatetest" with {"rootTag":1,"initialProps":{}}
 LOG  App state active
 LOG  App state inactive
 LOG  App state background
```

App state active is being output as the app first starts. App state inactive is being output as you start to swipe up and app state background is output as the app closes.

Comment: How come I get 59 logs of "App state background" and the same with "App state active" when i switch between states?

Comment: The console log in the else clause will be executed whenever the event listener is triggered which can be quite frequent. You could remove the else clause entirely if you have no use for that output.